# How can I mock the webkit SpeechRecognition using Jest?

Tags: jestjs, stenciljs

I am using webkit SpeechRecognition in my Stencil Project. I have shared function. Can anyone help me with the test cases of below function.

```js
startDictation() {
  let recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = false;
  recognition.interimResults = false;
  recognition.lang = "en-US";
  recognition.start();
  recognition.onresult = (speech) => {
    if (speech.results) {
      ele.classList.remove("dxp-i-fill");
      let result = speech.results[speech.resultIndex];
      let transcript = result[0].transcript;
      if (result.isFinal) {
        if (result[0].confidence < 0.3) {
          console.log("Unrecognized result - Please try again");
        } else {
          this.chatbotnputRef.value = transcript;
        }
      }
    }
  };
  recognition.onerror = function () {
    recognition.stop();
  };
}
```